# Why doesn't 'cap deploy:migrations' call my callbacks like 'before :deploy'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

cap deploy:migrations is supposed to run the same stuff as 'cap deploy' plus migrations. But it doesn't trigger my callbacks such as 'before :deploy'. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug (or not-implemented depending on how you look at it), and you can find more info here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/198